# Selenium : Test WebElements whose CSS attribute "OVERFLOW" is auto/scroll

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

In the following page, Only three elements are displayed, I have to use scroll bar to see others. 
I'm using selenium webdriver. 
 ElementNotVisibleException was thrown when I tried to click on the "Fourth Row" or the "Fifth Row".
Is there any method to move the scoll bar(or other way?) to make the "Fourth Row" and the "Fifth Row" visible, then clickable?

[image: WebElement with scoll bar]

```
<b>Source code of this element:</b>
<pre>
<html><body>
<div style="WIDTH: 215px; HEIGHT: 50px; OVERFLOW: auto; background-color:#66FFCC">
<ul>
<li><div>First Row</div></li>
<li><div>Second Row</div></li>
<li><div>Third Row</div></li>
<li><div>Fourth Row</div></li>
<li><div>Fifth Row</div></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body></html>
```

Comment: initially is the scroll bar hidden?..

Answer (score 4):

Well, I haven't seen any selenium api to do this.

But with `JavaScriptExecutor` you can do this.

Here is how

```
//Select element by some method

WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.id("elementid"));

// create JSExecutor object

JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;

// Do the JS click 

executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", we);
```

Comment: **Thank you, @DigvijayYadav, @Amith003** .              JavascriptExecutor works well. **Is there some way to simulate the motion of the middle key(the wheel) of the mouse?**  If this is possible, I would be able to put the mouse over the list and turn the middle key to show the hidden elements.

Comment: @user2432405: As of now I don't know if there is any way to simulate the action of the mouse wheel, but if your scroll container was in a separate iframe then you could possibly again use the `javascriptexecutor` to scroll. For more advanced user interaction you might want to look at this: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AdvancedUserInteractions#Mouse

Answer (score 0):

**forth row** or **fifth row** wont be visible initially,you will have to hover on top of its context to make it visible..
easiest way to click on it directly would be to use javascriptExecuter,

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("$('html ul li+li+li+li>div').click();");
```

If you could use attributes like id,name..etc ,finding elements would be much more easier, faster and efficient..
The above code will click on "forth row"..

Comment: This assumes jQuery is present on the page.