# Selenium-Java Webdriver: I am getting error as Element should have been "select" but was "input" when i select the value form dropdown box

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, browser-automation

Error message "Element should have been "select" but was "input""is shown when i select the value form drop down box. I have tried with selectByValue() amd selectByIndex().

HTML:

```
<div class="rcbScroll rcbWidth" style="width: 100%; overflow: auto; height: 40px;">
<ul class="rcbList" style="list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0;zoom:1;">
<li class="rcbItem">TIN</li>
<li class="rcbHovered">SSN</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

java code is:

```
Select select=new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(OR.getProperty("SSN"))));
select.selectByValue("SSN");
```

Comment: The above code will only work with <select> tag. I cannot find any <select> tag in the above code ?

Comment: i have tried with selectByValue()  but nothing :(

Comment: The error is pretty self-explanatory. You are attempting to use the `Select` class to manipulate a `ul` element (unordered list). This isn't possible merely because the `Select` class was created and is used for `select` (i.e dropdowns) elements only. I fear you are using a web application that styles the list to make it *look like* a dropdown, thus giving the illusion it is -> but it is clear this is not an ordinary dropdown.

Comment: you can refer [this for more info on this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19514256/selenium-test-webelements-whose-css-attribute-overflow-is-auto-scroll/19515325#19515325)

Answer (score 1):

You can apply `select` to select value from drop down, there is an `li` element there and you try to implement using `select` thats why it thrown the exception

Answer (score 0):

Yo can Select element by following method

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(OR.getProperty("SSN")).click();
```

In Next line select desired drop down in following way :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[text() = 'SSN']")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
Element should have been "select" but was "input"
```

...implies that you have tried to select the value through an instance of *Select* object where as the desired element was not a part of any `<select>` parent tag.

As per the *HTML* you have shared to click on the *option* with text as **SSN** you can use the following code block :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='rcbScroll rcbWidth']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='rcbScroll rcbWidth']/ul//li[@class='rcbHovered' and contains(.,'SSN')]")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Select by will not work for you cuz you need select tag with options tags as sub tags for it.
Bellow html code is the correct format you need for using Selenium Select.

```
<select some-label-name=”display label” name=”some name” id=”some id” title=”some title” class=”class name”>
<option value=”0”>display label</option>
<option value=”1” selected=”1”>1</option>
<option value=”2”>2</option>
<option value=”3”>3</option>
</select>
```

To solve your problem you need to click on the dropdown list to open options then click on the option you need.